# Join Laravel tables

Tags: laravel

I have got three tables Kudos, Kudoscategories, and specialpost. I need to get the data from those tables and check the post id using a where condition.

I have attached the database table screenshot here 
[image]

[image]
[image]
I already tried this, but it's not getting any result.

```
$results = DB::table('kudos')
->select('kudos.description','kudoscategory.catname','kudoscategory.image','kudos.spid')
        ->join('kudoscategory', 'kudoscategory.id', '=', 'kudos.categoryid')
        ->where('kudos.spid', '=', $post_id)
        ->first();

        return $results;
```

What I need to do is get the results using below where condition  `newsfeed_special_posts.main_post_id = kudos.spid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add another join with `newsfeed_special_posts`.
The query will be like,

```
$results = DB::table('kudos')
->select('kudos.description','kudoscategory.catname','kudoscategory.image','kudos.spid')
        ->join('kudoscategory', 'kudoscategory.id', '=', 'kudos.categoryid')
        ->join('newsfeed_special_posts', 'newsfeed_special_posts.main_post_id', '=', 'kudos.spid')
        ->where('kudos.spid', '=', $post_id)
        ->first();

        return $results;
```

Though this is not a good practice for laravel. using laravel eloquent relationships will be more efficient for these results. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

you can still do it this way. still efficient to avoid sql injection since you are getting all the record from the 3 tables. seeing your table above, its not properly normalised. anywaye try this.

```
    $results = DB::table('kudos')
    ->leftjoin('kudoscategory', 'kudoscategory.id', '=', 'kudos.categoryid')
    ->leftjoin('newsfeed_special_posts', 'newsfeed_special_posts.id', '=', 'kudos.spid')
    ->where('kudos.spid', '=', $post_id)
    ->first();

    return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code 
at first, create model Kudos,KudosCategory,NewsfeedSpecialPosts

Kudos Model

```
public function kudoscategory_dta()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\KudosCategory','categoryid');
}

public function newsfeed_special_posts_dta()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\NewsfeedSpecialPosts','spid','main_post_id ');
}
```

controller

Kudos::with('kudoscategory_dta','newsfeed_special_posts_dta')->first();